# Xcode 5 minimum deployment target

Tags: ios, xcode5

Currently I am using Xcode 4.6. My app needs to support minimum iOS 4.3. I also want to expand upper limit support to iOS 7. Does Xcode 5, iOS SDK 7 still support iOS 4.3 ? And is iOS 4.3 simulator still available in Xcode 5 ?

I tried to read up [Xcode 5 Release Note](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/releasenotes/DeveloperTools/RN-Xcode/#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001051-SW241) but it does not mention anything. Thanks!

Comment: The old simulator is not available, but you can still deploy to 4.3 (for whatever reason). I'm sure you could install the old simulator from your current build. Or it may not get deleted even, when you install the new Xcode.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I think i'm going upgrade xcode.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you want ios 4.3 simulator in your xcode 5 then follow this process

1> Go your application folder and right click on older xcode

2.> Show package content > contents > Developer > Platforms > iPhoneSimulator.platform >Developer > SDKs

3> Now copy this "iPhoneSimulator4.3.sdk" and follow this same directory structure for new xcode version and past this "iPhoneSimulator4.3.sdk" into "SDKs" folder along with "iPhoneSimulator7.0.sdk".

4> restart xcode and then open your project . It will start showing 4.3 along with 7.

Comment: Please see my updated answer and try this. And now deploy for target that you want.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. This would be helpful if I ever encounter that my 4.3 simulator is lost with the upgrade.