# ios 6.0 Simulator in xcode 5.1

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, ios7.1, xcode5.1

I just successfully updated my Xcode tool to 5.1 version and when I check Downloads option in preference section then I noticed there is no option to download ios 6.0 simulator.(Please check attached image)

[image]

So how can I access ios 6.0 simulator in Xcode 5.1?

Comment: I suppose you could copy in the 6.0 SDK from some other Xcode version. But basically this just seems to be something Apple wants us to accept. They seem to have thrown a switch at the server end to make the 6.0 simulator no longer available.

Comment: ok. means If I want to test my app in ios6.0 then I need to test it in older version(xcode 5.0 or 5.0.2)

Comment: ok. It can be done with copy sdk to new version also. Thanks !!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please follow this procedure to upgrade your xCode

[Upgrade xCode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19045981/xcode-5-minimum-deployment-target/19046020#19046020)

At last change deployment target to access both IOS 6 and IOS 7 simulators.

Answer (score 2):

There are basically no difference between IOS 6.0 and IOS 6.1, in 6.1 apple just added three header file with few method in `MapKit framework` and did little modification in `UIKit`. So I don't think that you should bother about that.

[You can check the modification here](https://developer.apple.com/library/iOs/releasenotes/General/iOS61APIDiffs/index.html)