# Install ios 5 simulator to xcode 5.1?

Tags: ios, xcode

I am currently using xcode 5.1 with Mac 10.8.5. But i can not install ios simulator in this xcode? any one tell me how to install ios 5 simulator ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22342092/ios-6-0-simulator-in-xcode-5-1

Answer (score 7):

Man, this *really* made me angry today when I upgraded from Xcode 5.0 to Xcode 5.1 and discovered that I no longer had a functional iOS 5.1 simulator. There was *nothing* in the Software Update process that gave me any heads-up whatsoever that this would disable iOS 5.0/5.1 simulators. Bad Apple! Bad!

Anyway, here's the workaround I came up with. It seems pretty clean.

1. I noticed that in `~/Library/Caches/com.apple.dt.Xcode/Downloads` there was an old file sitting around called `Xcode.SDK.iPhoneSimulator.5.1-5.1.dmg` (thank god I never cleared out that cache directory).
2. I double-clicked this disk image to mount it, and then double-clicked the .pkg file inside that. The package installer then placed the contents into a subdirectory of `/Platforms`.
3. I then moved `/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator5.1.sdk` into `/Applications/Xcode/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs` and restarted Xcode.

Bam. Done. Back in business.

Note: Another approach, if you happen to have a thorough Time Machine backup of your full system, as Pandey Laxman pointed out earlier, is simply to restore the contents of `/Applications/Xcode/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator5.1.sdk` from an older backup. In my case, I wasn't able to do this because my development system is a MacBook Air that I keep backed via Time Machine up onto a permanently-installed 32GB SanDisk Cruzer Fit USB flash drive (as well as two extra Time Machine backups on separate network drives). Anyway, because the backup drive is relatively small, when I first set up Time Machine on this system, I had excluded `/Applications` from my backup (something I don't recommend doing).

Comment: @EngrAnum — Great!!! I also made a special off-site backup (separate from Time Machine) of all my `~/Library/Caches/com.apple.dt.Xcode/Downloads` files, just in case I ever need any of these again — as I doubt I'll ever be able to find them from Apple in the future (although I would love to be proven wrong about that!).

Comment: I don't have a previous version of Xcode :( Do you think it could be possible to share the 5.0 simulator somewhere? Thanks!

Comment: @Yako — Guess what? Found the iOS 5.1 Simulator & SDK archived at Apple's website. To obtain it, you'll need to download the Xcode 4.4.1 disk image, mount it, and then inside the `Xcode.app` (right click and select "Show Package Contents") directory, drill down to `Contents/Developer/Platforms` and you will find the directories needed to install as described in the answer above. Here is the URL: https://developer.apple.com/downloads/index.action?name=Xcode%204.4.1

Comment: It now says "The requested iOS simulator is not supported by the iOS simulator."

Comment: @JamesO'Brien — Hi, what do you mean by "it"? Which version of Xcode are you seeing this error message with? 5.1? 5.1.1? 6?

Comment: @ToddLehman, I see this as well -- XCode 5.1.1 on OSX10.9.3.  More info: iOS5.1 shows as an option for retina sim 3.5 inch in XCode, but the sim app itself shows only 6.1 and 7.1 as options for the 3.5 retina. -- UPDATE: I see from below as well as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19540739/xcode-5-0-1-and-ios-5-1-simulator-issue that 5.1 isn't supported on Mav.  Boohoo.

Comment: Man, I'm so glad I haven't upgraded to Mavericks yet. I do have an old iOS 5 iPad handy, but it's nowhere near as handy as the simulator. So there is really no way at all (even with jumping through hoops) to make the iOS 5 simulator run properly on Mavericks? :(

Comment: @ToddLehman Long time ago, don't remember, but I think it was XCode 5 something giving me the error

Answer (score 4):

In order to develop for the latest version of iOS, you need the latest iOS SDK, which requires the latest version of XCode, which in turn requires the latest version of OSX (at least as of writing this iOS 8.3 requires XCode 6.3, which requires OSX 10.10 - all the latest and greatest).

I would guess that Apple doesn't want to support iPad 1s and old iPhones anymore running iOS 5.  Thus, they've done what they could to discourage developers from supportting them.

I, personal, put a lot of effort into coding to support iOS 5 through 8.  I am not in hurry to throw that backwards compatibility away, but obviously developing for the most current version of iOS takes priority.

To get to the point, you can't install or run an iOS 5 simulator on OSX 10.10 Yosemite.  I couldn't get an iOS 6 simulator to run either for some reason (even though I was able to install it in XCode 5).

I did, however, find a solution so I could use simulators for iOS 5 through 8 on my machine.

How?  Setup a dual boot into an older os and install some software which can no longer be downloaded, but I tracked down.

I've posted the steps and all the software here.  Nothing is difficult about any of this, but it will take many hour of downloading and running installations, ect.  Reserve a day to do this while working another machine most of the time.

1. Create a partition on your hard drive from which you can run OSX Lion.  I found 32 GB was large enough.
   You may also want to create an additional partition at the same time rather than use a flash drive in step 2.  I also made it 32 GB, but it could probably be a lot smaller (8? maybe even 4 gig?).

Here's a link to help with that:

http://arstechnica.com/apple/2014/06/how-to-create-a-test-partition-for-the-os-x-yosemite-beta/

2. Create a bootable installer drive for Lion.  You can use a flash drive, or the extra partition suggested in step 1 (that's what I did when the only flash I had on me was acting up).

Here's the os:

OSX 10.7.2 Lion
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BwmycZWygE8EUlhCYWlOWjlCcHM/view?usp=sharing

Here's directions for doing this:

http://www.tech-recipes.com/rx/11807/os-x-lion-convert-os-x-lion-dmg-installer-to-a-bootable-usb-thumbdrive-install-without-an-optical-drive/

3. Run the installer.  Restart the machine whiling holding down the "option" key on the keyboard to select your boot device.
4. Once you have Lion up and running, you need to upgrade it to 10.7.5 (sorry I didn't have that to post to begin with).
   Simply use the basic software update mechanism to do this.
5. Install XCode 4.6.  Here's the software:

XCode 4.6.3
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BwmycZWygE8ETnlFQ1BSYVV1ZUE/view?usp=sharing

6. Normally, you ought to be able to install an iOS 5 simulator via XCode, but Apple has blocked this.
   You can however, install it manually as others have described in this thread for the various sdks (as long as you already have the software!)

Here is the software (since we don't have just happen to be lucky enough to have it previously installed):
Sorry, I don't have 5.1, only 5.0

iOS 5.0 Simulator
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BwmycZWygE8ETndPOFJyUVg0b3M/view?usp=sharing

7. Install the command line tools if necessary.  Again, XCode ought to allow you to do this, but it will fail when you try the normal way.  Go ahead and give it a try.
   Here's a dmg instead which you can install yourself that is compatible with this setup:

Command Line Tools (XCode 4.6 / OSX 10.7)
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BwmycZWygE8EWm9QTW5HYV9PUnM/view?usp=sharing

8. Get your project to build in this new environment.  There are permission issues and such when you try to cross over to your primary drive.
   I found the easiest way to get everything working was to copy whatever I needed to the Lion drive and make sure all the relative paths were identical.
   I also had to play a bit with the code because what compiled for the 7 and 8 sdks didn't work perfectly with this one.  That's on you.
9. I believe the iOS 6 simulator will already be installed for you, but otherwise you should be able to download that still via XCode if needed.

Enjoy having all these simulators now!

Comment: @BuvinJ, how to install this iOS 5.0 simulator?

Comment: Extract the sdk file from the zip after you download it. Then copy to the XCode simulator sdk directory.  Refer to Pandey_Laxman's post (near the top of this thread), which is stating the same thing.  As I recall, XCode will then see this simulator as an option automatically.  (You might need to restart XCode?)

Answer (score 2):

you need to copy the simulator SDK to Xcode 5.1.

First copy the simulator SDKs from your previous installed Xcode.

then paste it in 
Xcode 5.1 **"Show Package Contents->Contents->Developer->Platforms->iPhoneSimulator.Platforms
->Developer->SDKs** folder

There restart the Xcode 5.1.

Answer (score 1):

Unfrotunately ,Xcode 5.1 in OS X 10.9 or 10.8.5 the iOS 5 simulator is no longer available.

Better to use some older versions like 4.6 for use iOS 5 simulator

Answer (score 1):

using of Xcode 5 under OS X v10.8 then if you go to `Preferences -> Downloads` you should see the 5.0 and 5.1 simulators available under **Components**. You can download and install directly from there.

> If you're using Xcode 5 under OS X v10.9 then the iOS 5 simulator is
>   no longer available.

Answer (score 1):

xCode 5.02 up to available iOS 58 simulator but after updated the xcode through 5.1 the available simulator start from iOS 6

[image]

## iOS Simulator

Performance issues can arise when running apps within the iOS Simulator on OS X Mavericks with a simulated OS version of iOS 6.1 or earlier.
A workaround is to disable timer coalescing while using the iOS 6.1 or earlier simulator by executing the following command in a Terminal window:

```
sudo sysctl -w kern.timer.coalescing_enabled=0 (15501929)
```

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/releasenotes/DeveloperTools/RN-Xcode/xc5_release_notes/xc5_release_notes.html