# Apple Mach-O Linker Error in architecture x86_64

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, linker, cocoapods

I'm getting the following linker error:

```
Ld /Users/premedios/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Tweepr-chpytouktuxjlfehpsynwphlgwzo/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Tweepr.app/Tweepr normal x86_64
cd /Users/premedios/Developer/Objective-C/tweepr-3
export IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=6.0
export PATH="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang -arch x86_64 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator8.1.sdk -L/Users/premedios/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Tweepr-chpytouktuxjlfehpsynwphlgwzo/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -F/Users/premedios/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Tweepr-chpytouktuxjlfehpsynwphlgwzo/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -F/Users/premedios/Developer/Objective-C/tweepr-3/iUnfollow/Classes/Library -filelist /Users/premedios/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Tweepr-chpytouktuxjlfehpsynwphlgwzo/Build/Intermediates/Tweepr.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Tweepr.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/Tweepr.LinkFileList -Xlinker -objc_abi_version -Xlinker 2 -ObjC -fobjc-arc -fobjc-link-runtime -Xlinker -no_implicit_dylibs -mios-simulator-version-min=6.0 -framework Accelerate -framework Social -framework Security -framework StoreKit -framework ImageIO -framework MapKit -framework CoreText -framework CoreTelephony -lz -framework MobileCoreServices -framework Accounts -framework Twitter -framework CoreData -framework SystemConfiguration -framework CoreFoundation -framework CFNetwork -framework UIKit -framework Foundation -framework CoreGraphics -framework QuartzCore -lPods -Xlinker -dependency_info -Xlinker /Users/premedios/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Tweepr-chpytouktuxjlfehpsynwphlgwzo/Build/Intermediates/Tweepr.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Tweepr.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/Tweepr_dependency_info.dat -o /Users/premedios/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Tweepr-chpytouktuxjlfehpsynwphlgwzo/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Tweepr.app/Tweepr

Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
"_OBJC_CLASS_$_STTwitterAPI", referenced from:
  objc-class-ref in NetworkManager.o
"_OBJC_CLASS_$_SVProgressHUD", referenced from:
  objc-class-ref in Utils.o
  objc-class-ref in NetworkManager.o
  objc-class-ref in TPRIAPManager.o
"_OBJC_CLASS_$_SimpleAuth", referenced from:
  objc-class-ref in TPRAppDelegate.o
  objc-class-ref in UserLoadingRoutine.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I tried "Clean Build Folder", but the error persists. Anyone have any other ideas on the cause of this?

Comment: are you using any framework or library? please post complete error log, there should be the name of framework causing the problem. x86_64 is architecture for 64 bit simulators in ios, the library must be missing that architecture support.

Comment: @IrfanGul I added more from the error log

Comment: what is your project deployment target is it ios 6? which xcode version your using and on which simulator (ios version) your trying to debug code?

Comment: try to clean the DerivedData first . xcode > preferences >  location tab > open deriveddata location delete all files under it.

Comment: Yes the project deployment target is iOS 6. I'm using Xcode 6.1.1 and the simulator is iPhone 6.

Comment: I cleared DerivedData but the error remains.

Comment: change deployment target to 7.1 or later. It should work now.

Comment: Check this link, I think the problem is same as your one.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26637260/ios-6-1-simulator-on-osx-10-10-yosemite