# Is there a way to get iOS 7 simulator on Xcode 7

Tags: ios, xcode, ios-simulator

I just updated my Xcode to the newest version (7.0 7A220) and I lost the iOS 7 simulator that I had in the previous version. I still have the iOS 7 SDK and was wondering if there is way to use it on the newest version of Xcode, instead of installing another version of Xcode on my OS X.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As for my initial analysis referred from [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25896559/install-ios-6-simulator-on-xcode-6) you cant install it and use older version of Xcode version for using respective iOS simulators. To use iOS 7.1 go for Xcode 6.4 or earlier. Install Xcode 6.4 and download respective simulator from Preference.

[image]

To download older version of Xcode you need to login with developer account https://developer.apple.com/downloads/
[image]

Comment: that's what I did now I have both Xcode 7 and 6.4 on my OS X (I need both iOS 9 and iOS 7 simulators), I changed the name of the second to Xcode2.app

Comment: http://www.macrumors.com/2015/09/17/early-ios-9-adoption-rate/ check the iOS 9 adoption rate here. soon all devices updated to iOS 8 & 9 since this updates in Xcode.

Comment: My project won't compile using Xcode 6.4 (because of nullability additions), so I guess there's no solution in my case.

Comment: You could start the 7.1 simulator manually from Xcode 6.4 install location and before you launch it, make a copy of your compiled app binary from Debug-iphonesimulator location of a Xcode 7.2 build to the app location of the 7.1 simulator device. Both locations may be fiddling to find, but it's possible to attach to the running app in the 7.1 simulator from Xcode 7.2 even with a 9.2 SDK built copy. breakpoints are working. it's a hack, but for some tests, why not…

Answer (score 8):

Download the official installation package from: https://devimages.apple.com.edgekey.net/downloads/xcode/simulators/com.apple.pkg.iPhoneSimulatorSDK7_1-7.1.1.1354140590.dmg

This is where Xcode 6.4 is downloading it from.
But it won't work on El Capitan, only on Yosemite. The runtime has a problem with El Capitan... So until Apple solves it (if they want to), we're stuck.

Comment: Where does this install to?

Comment: Apparently the above dmg does install (wherever it did…), but it doesn't launch in Xcode 7.2 (Yosemite) and simulator says it can't launch the simruntime.