# Xcode 8 no support iOS 7

Tags: ios, xcode

I've upgraded my Xcode to Xcode 8. Now I notice that I cannot run/debug on an iPhone with iOS 7.n.n. I've have read that it isn't supported in Xcode 8. I do know that my app will still work on iOS 7, but if something fails I would like to hang it on Xcode to debug it. So my question is:

Do I still get the bug fixes/improvement that were introduced in iOS 10 when submitting my app with a base sdk setting of iOS 9.3?

Comment: Can you be more clear about: "Do I still get the bug fixes/improvement that were introduced in iOS 10 when submitting my app with a base sdk setting of iOS 9.3?"

Comment: @AndersonOki Do I still get the improvements made in the latest SDK without settings it as my base SDK

Comment: No. Since it will be compiled using the old sdk version. The upversion changes will not be applied.

Comment: That is not true @AndersonOki, some libraries are dynamically linked, like SpriteKit, so even if you build for 9.3, you will still get the 10.0 bugs and optimizations, just none of the new features

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Do I still get the bug fixes/improvement that were introduced in iOS 10 when submitting my app with a base sdk setting of iOS 9.3?

No, of course not. If you do that, you are still an iOS 9 app. You must link against iOS 10 if you want to run natively under iOS 10.

However, you can do that and still be backward compatible to iOS 7. And you can easily test on an iOS 7 device, so the change to Xcode 8 does you no harm.

Answer (score 1):

Xcode 8 (or even Xcode 7) [doesn't include support for iOS 7 simulator, which is what I think you're really asking about](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32647792/is-there-a-way-to-get-ios-7-simulator-on-xcode-7).

To pick up the new iOS 10 SDK changes, link against the iOS 10 SDK and then set your target's minimum deployment version to iOS 7.

If you were using analytics, chances are very high that you'll find the number of iOS 7 using customers is incredibly low.