# Xcode 7.0 and iOS5 compatilibity

Tags: ipad, ios5, ios-simulator, xcode7

1) I cant use my iPad with iOS 5.1.1 in XCode 7.0 (7A220). 
In "Devices" window:

"Unsupported device model: "iPad is of a model that is not supported by this version of Xcode..."

2) Is impossible to upload iOS 5 simulator to Xcode 7; the oldest available is iOS 6.

What can I do to work this iPad withXcode 7?

Comment: The iOS 5.x simulator will not run on recent versions of OS X.  What you want to do is not supported, sorry.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

XCode hasn't supported iOS 5 simulation for longer than that.  Check my post on the thread [Install ios 5 simulator to xcode 5.1?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22479215/install-ios-5-simulator-to-xcode-5-1/30239188#30239188) to see how I ran iOS 5 simulators on a mac with recent versions of XCode loaded.

Comment: I saw the same error regarding the device. I would like to know, if XCode 7 can build ipa's with sdk 9 that run on gen 1 iPads w iOS 5.1.1?  I have build errors now preventing me from getting that far with my testing.

Comment: Summary I want install OS X Lion + XCode5  on external HD, and in this way programming for iOS5 device.

Comment: Essentially, yes.  Setup a dual boot with an old os which can run an old version of XCode, and install the simulator from the file I posted (which can no longer be downloaded from Apple).

Comment: I did it. OS X Lion & Xcode 5 on ext. HDD. Common source files for this and for the Xcode 7 on main HDD; one diffrent is *.xcodeproj and info.plist. Work ideally.

Comment: @skippy do you have two different builds and apps in App Store with your workaround?

Comment: @SoundBlaster you don't submit separate builds / apps.  You now submit one which contains dual 32 / 64 bit architectures.  Unfortunately, you can't test that with your own iap or install via XCode.  The store handles which one is installed on a given device instead.

Comment: I use it for testing on my old device, but isnt possible to upload it to appstore